# Nested Json Access Value

Tags: javascript, json, nested

Here is my Json-String:

```js
{
    "batchcomplete":"",
    "query":{
        "pages":{
            "104352":{
                "pageid":104352,
                "ns":0,
                "title":"student"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to access tha first number, in this example "103452", not the on after pageid, although they always *should* be the same.
I tried the following until know, but don´t get why it wont work.

JSONName.query.pages;

it always returns me Object object.

Comment: There's no such thing as a *JSON Object* – JSON is *always* a string.

Comment: thanks for that explanation, i mixed that up...

Comment: You can use `Object.entries`, `Object.keys` or `Object.values` to iterate through an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a JavaScript object you can get the keys of an object which would contain your string.

```js
const obj = {
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "104352": {
        "pageid": 104352,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "student"
      }
    }
  }
}

// Get the keys for pages
const keys = Object.keys(obj.query.pages);

// Print out the first key
console.log(keys[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to find it during the parsing:

```js
var n, j = '{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"104352":{"pageid":104352,"ns":0,"title":"student"}}}}';

var result = JSON.parse(j, (key, value) => (n = n || +key, value));

console.log( n ); console.log( result );
```